# DOM manipulation causes SWF reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, flash

I am using jQuery to insert an SWF into the DOM.
When the SWF is loaded, and I try to clone it or wrap it, the SWF reloads.

It is important to me that this does not happen.

Below, an example:

```
$('#test9').before('<p></p>');
$('#test9').clone(true,true).appendTo($('p'));
```

where `#test9` is a swf object.
Could you help me to avoid this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the SWF reloads"? What are you expecting?

Comment: Can you edit the source of this SWF?

Comment: @thirtydit :I can edit source of the SWF. I have tried to use Sahred Object in AS3, but the problem is always here.

Comment: @LekisS : I mean the embed object disappear and appear again

Answer (score 0):

.swf is a file format that is somewhat comparable with a program. You cannot just launch it at a certain state, it will initialize at the beginning of the program. So if you clone it, it will automatically relaunch.
No es possible, is it really necessary for you to clone the swf? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want make something like "sIFR" (for text replacement), and this text is in jScrollpane. jScrollpane use "clone" to copy html content in a container wich is scrollable.

Comment: I try to use webfont, font-face, cufon, facelift ... etc, but the result is aliased and very poor. So I used flash to have "correct" result.

Comment: Hmz, that's a bummer. I don't know if there's a way to accomplish what you're trying with flash. Good luck!

Comment: that's what I thought sadly. Thanks anyway